# FastAPI Pydantic Mongo: Store existing ObjectId in another model(Foreign Key)

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi, pydantic

Hello I'm new to FastAPI so apologize if this sounds stupid. I have two collections, Customer and Account. Customer has a list of accounts. On each Account object, there is a customer identifier which is actually the objectId of the customer collection.

I have used `json.ENCODERS_BY_TYPE[ObjectId]=str`

The problem with this is the customer identifier is being stored as a string and not as an ObjectId. How do I make pydantic/ update the extra_schema in such a way that it gets stored as an ObjectId in the database?

Additionally I tried to use `bson.ObjectId()` to create a new objectId for customer identifier but end up getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pydantic\validators.py", line 751, in pydantic.validators.find_validators
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
RuntimeError: error checking inheritance of ObjectId('645e254d25af0724dc6adac6') (type: ObjectId)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you read the articles on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then use the _Edit_ function to modify your question accordingly.
The practice of boiling the code down to the bare minimum needed to capture the essence of the problem not only motivates others to actually try and help you but more often than not gives you a deeper understanding to solve the problem yourself.